# Rails 3: using composed_of with validation causes ActiveRecord error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, ip-address

I am using the following [code snippet from the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-composed_of) to convert IPs into integers before inserting them into the database:

```
composed_of :user_ip,
            :class_name => 'IPAddr',
            :mapping => %w(user_ip to_i),
            :constructor => Proc.new { |ip| IPAddr.new(ip, Socket::AF_INET) },
            :converter => Proc.new { |ip| ip.is_a?(Integer) ? IPAddr.new(ip, Socket::AF_INET) : IPAddr.new(ip.to_s) }
```

The composed_of block is then followed by this simple validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_ip
```

But the validation in turn throws an error when trying to create a new object:

```
TypeError: Cannot visit IPAddr
```

Remove the validation and the error is gone.

If I understand correctly, this is happening because :user_ip becomes an IPAddr object, and that does not sit well with ActiveRecord. Is this correct, and if so, is there a way around it?

Comment: You are correct, but unfortunately I don't have a solution for you. I've been trying to figure this one out for a while since a gem I wrote has the same problem.

Comment: The solution isn't simple.  I think it involves reopening IPAddr and adding `include ActiveRecord::Validations`, but there's a lot more to it than that.  Once you do that include, you have to also add in a bunch of methods Rails would expect an ActiveRecord::Base class to have, and I think you have to override some part of the uniqueness validator.  I might try to tackle this and provide an answer tomorrow if I have time, but I can't make any promises.  Maybe this is enough to help you make some progress.

Comment: @Ryan did you ever figure out a solution to this? You had posted some ideas and I was curious if you got anywhere with it.

Comment: @Beerlington I didn't get very far with it, unfortunately.  I still think I was on the right track, but wasn't able to devote enough time to it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found a solution to this, but I was able to patch it in my gem by adding a visit method to Arel.

You should be able to do something like the following to get it to work. This is based on how [Arel converts values](https://github.com/brynary/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L379) for other types of objects such as dates. Not sure if you need to convert the value to a string, but it might just work as an integer.

```
module Arel
  module Visitors
    class ToSql
      def visit_IPAddr
        quote(value.to_i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I needed to be able to dynamically generate these methods so I used the following in my gem:

```
Arel::Visitors::ToSql.class_eval do
  define_method "visit_#{klass.name}", lambda {|value| quote(value.to_s) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I never bothered finding a solution but if I was to try today I would abandon IPAddr and try converting the IPs using inject methods (which work faster anyway)

Comment: The signature of `visit_IPAddr` varies depending on the version of Arel you need to support. In Arel 4.0.2 (which is used in Rails 4.0), it should be `visit_IPAddr(object, attribute)`, and in the latest it should be `visit_IPAddr(object)`. In either case, use the given `object` instead of `value` within the method.